# Unable to import Lightgbm in Jupyter notebook on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, lightgbm, gbm

I am able to install Lightgbm using the command below:

***pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org lightgbm***

I am able to see it installed by using Conda list as well.

However,after that I am unable to import the package into Jupyter notebook.

I am getting the below error.

***import lightgbm***

AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods'`

I tried the above methods but in vain.There are multiple other error lines as well indicating dask.dataframe error which I am unable to find out the method to cure.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [microsoft/LightGBM#5379](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5739#issuecomment-1500809138), `dask<2023.2.0` is not compatible with `pandas>=2.0`.

Though you haven't included details like the output of `conda-env export` or `pip freeze`, I strongly suspect you have such versions of those libraries.

Either remove `dask` from your environment ...

```bash
pip uninstall --yes \
    dask
```

... or upgrade it and `distributed` to a newer version

```bash
pip install \
    'dask>2023.3.2' \
    'distributed>2023.3.2'
```

After doing one of those, restart your notebook's kernel, and you should be able to import `lightgbm` without facing this issue.

```py
import lightgbm
```